# FB JavaScript SDK is giving wrong permissions dialog for my friend, but new one for me

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Currently, I'm using

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
<script> 
FB.init({
    appId: '214620658601362',
    cookie: true,
    status: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true
});
$(function() {
    $("#login").click(function() {
        FB.login(function() {
            alert('logged in');
        }, {
            scope: 'publish_actions'
        });
    });
});
```

code to get authenticated into my dummy application. Problem is that my friend see the old permissions dialog, it means he can't approve my application's "publish_actions" permission. I see the new one. When I try to publish action, error appears:

```
 FB.ApiServer._callbacks.f3209b810({"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException"}});
```

however, it works for me

My friend (wrong one):
[image]

Me (correct one):
[image]

am I missing something in my login code?

Comment: Is your friend participating in the new Developer's Timeline early access beta?

Comment: @ifaour: yeah, before few minutes he activated it

Comment: I think it make sense **not** to be able to see the new dialog if he is not in the beta program.

Comment: I DID READ YOUR COMMENT! BUT YOUR SECOND COMMENT IMPLIED THIS: "if he didn't activated the beta would it show the old or new dialog?"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second screenshot is a dialog which hasn't launched for every application/user; if your friend enabled the Timeline beta as a developer, he'd likely be seeing the new dialog.
It's not clear if he's a developer of the app you're trying to authorize; if so, it makes it even more likely.

Comment: oh, wait. He isn't developer of my application, but developer of another. does it matter?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but definitely that's a new dialog that most users won't see, the first screenshot is what most users will see at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Your friend probably needs to clear their browser cache so that it has to reload the page from its source, not from what is cached on disk.

Comment: he didn't access that page before, so I doubt it would be cache problem. I'll tell him when he's back online, though